# C++ STL Breadth first search

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
int x;
cin >> x;
for(int tt=0;tt<x;tt++)
    {
    //cout << "HI" << endl;
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector< vector<int> > g(n);
    for(long j =0; j< m;j++)
        {
        int u , v;
        cin  >> u >> v;

        g[u-1].push_back(v-1);
        g[v-1].push_back(u-1);

    }

    int s;
    cin >> s;

    vector<int> out(n,-1);
    vector<int> visited(n,0);
    int value = 0;
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(s-1);
    q.push(-1);
    visited[s-1] =1;
    int flag =0;
    while(!q.empty())
        {
        int v = q.front();
        out[v] = value;
        q.pop();
        if(v == -1)
            {
            value += 6;
        }
        else{
            for(vector<int>::iterator it = g[v].begin(); it != g[v].end();it++)
                {
                if(visited[*it] == 0)
                    {
                    q.push(*it);
                    visited[*it] =1;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //cout << "hello" << endl;
    for(int k =0; k<n; k++)
        {
        if(k!= s-1)
            {
            cout << out[k] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    //cout << "yo";
}
//cout << "you";
return 0;
}
```

This code works well if the start node has only 1st level neighbour. To make it work for all cases, when i change

```
if(v == -1)
{
       value += 6;
}
```

to

```
if(v == -1)
{
     value += 6;
     if(!q.empty())
          q.push(-1);
}
```

it doesn't even work for all testcases now. Then the program is aborted and the error message from hacker rank is 
*** Error in `solution': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000009e5cf0 ***

I can't figure out why this is happening. Why is there a problem in for loop when I am processing the queue.

Link to the hackerrank question.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bfsshortreach

Comment: You go out of bounds for one of your vectors. Add some bounds checking, but more importantly add some **validation of the input**.

Comment: Lets skip all the nitty details and look at the most suspicious sequence of statements: `q.push(-1); int v = q.front(); out[v] = value;`.

Comment: breadth-first search. Put the root in a  queue. Whilst the queue is not empty, take the first member, and add immediate children to the back of the queue. So you need a std::deque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

1. get rid of `value` , it is not required.
2. the vector out of bounds access was there. what is out[-1] ?
3. proper indentation
4. Bfs always visits level wise. You don't need to maintain it by pushing negative value in queue.

The correct code is:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int x,n, m,u , v;
    cin >> x;
    for(int tt=0;tt<x;tt++){
        cin >> n >> m;
        vector< vector<int> > g(n);
        for(long j =0; j< m;j++){
            cin  >> u >> v;
            g[u-1].push_back(v-1);
            g[v-1].push_back(u-1);
        }

        int s;
        cin >> s;

        vector<int> out(n,-1);
        vector<bool> visited(n,0);
        queue< int > q;
        q.push(s-1);
        visited[s-1] =1;
        out[s-1]=0;

        while(!q.empty()){
            int v = q.front(); q.pop();

            for(vector<int>::iterator it = g[v].begin(); it != g[v].end();it++){
                if(visited[*it] == 0){
                    q.push(*it);
                    visited[*it] =1;
                    out[*it]=out[v]+6;
                }
            }

        }
        for(int k =0; k<n; k++){
            if(k!= s-1){
                cout << out[k] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there an answer in here?

Comment: Posting changed code without any trait of explanation... -1 for now.

Comment: @Hurkyl, Only people who read the problem carefully get to know the difference, my friend.

Comment: @grek40, Dude you were too fast. the explanations were coming. I was busy in the code then.

Comment: @dd2 It's a thing I personally don't like. My understanding is, that people should ask complete questions and post somewhat complete answers. Posting a placeholder for whatever reason (in order to be faster than other answers) and then working on the actual answer means, that others will look at the placeholder and see a bad answer.

Comment: @dd2 Thanks !! yeah so out[-1] :(  I do a lot of careless mistakes. Well I was using -1 to keep track of the level. Yeah yours code is awesome. I didn't need that here.

Comment: @user2871856, thanks , At least there are some who really appreciate the effort. I just corrected some obvious mistakes and my code was very simple to understand. right? I guess I made myself clear now grek40 and Hurky

Comment: @dd2 I had already removed the -1 when I wrote my second comment, I'm not the domestic dragon of stackoverflow, so I won't haunt people forever for their first draft ;)